# How to call a method defined in main.cpp from another .cpp source file?

Tags: c++, program-entry-point

First, this is a general question

Second: I thought of it because right now it complicated things in a project of mine. Don't worry I got a workaround, but I'd still want to know if there had been another way of solving it.

getting to the question:

I have my main.cpp. I defined some methods and functions in it. I have some other files with other functions and stuff too, but now I need a function that works with temporary variables that are defined in the main.cpp. 
How can I extend the scope of such a variable so that I can use it in other files also?

From classes, I know that fields can be private or public. But what about this variable? Is it private? public? something else? can I create a getter/setter for this variable? I can't even include the main.cpp in another since it would be recursive and I'd have main defined infinite times then ....)

The main questions would be:

How can I access a variable defined in my main.cpp in another file?

some example code:

in main.cpp:

```
int var = 0;

int getVar() {
    return var;
}


void doVar() {
    // sth happens with var
}

int main() {
    MyObject myObj;

    doVar();
}
```

in MyObject.cpp:

```
class MyObject {
    void DoSth(){
        // NEEDS var from main.cpp, to do sth with it!
        // getVar() doesn't work!
        // doVar() doesn't work either!
    }
}
```

Forgive me if this is a previously asked or really stupid question, but I was really wondering about that just now

My workaround was that I made doVar and var to members of MyObject (i.e. now its all in the same file MyObject.cpp), but is this the only way?

Comment: why the downvote? would you mind explaining it at least?

Comment: I guess you could write `extern int var;` in MyObject.cpp and go with that if you really want a global, but maybe there's a better solution. It's not clear to me what you're trying to achieve. (and the downvote's not mine. I'm out of votes!)

Comment: what would it do? I just googled and came up with something similiar to 'static', is that right? so what's the difference?

Comment: downvoted, because `private` and `public` keywords only have a meaning inside a class [see e.g. here](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/access).

Comment: `extern` basically tells the compiler that this variable exists, but is defined in another source file.

Comment: so where do I define it then? in the MyObject.cpp?

Comment: @tobi303 I thought as much, but I don't get the real reason for the downvote then if you could just explain it too - can you explain what kind of 'thing' the main instance is then?

Comment: Just to avoid a misunderstanding: I didnt downvote because you didnt know, but because you could have found out rather easily. It seems like you are missing some basic concepts and I can only suggest you to get a C++ book, because learning C++ by trial and error is a nightmare (believe me, I tried myself ;)

Comment: That's why I asked this question, and yes I know I have to learn way more about it then I know right now. I'd like to avoid that too and I found something to do just that. That doesn't mean I won't come up with such a silly question once in a while, so please just tell me to begin with ^^

Comment: @tobi303 The downvote was unfounded. The question is helpful for future research, well explained and complete enough in samples to reanact, what's the source of the actual error, and how to fix it. So what? Knowing about the differences of access policies in various scopes compared to C isn't easy to find out, and easily can be misunderstood because of totally different semantics of the `static` keyword.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ I found it confusing when reading and I still think the question would be nicer if he didnt mention private / public. Anyhow, I undid downvote and maybe will propose an edit instead

Comment: @tobi303 _" I found it confusing when reading"_ Then probably the better action is to propose an edit with highlights, and better structuring than just downvote.

Comment: _@blueBurningCoder_ In fact @tobi303 had some valid point, it's not so easy to grip from your question description what you're actually after. Well, I assumed you're coming from some C language (alike) background, and just tried my best to explain about these _access scope policies_ and how they differ from `static` usage in C. You should consider to improve your question (please leave it as a question), along the highlighted cites I put into my answer.

Comment: Ehm Thanks, and yeah I'll leave it, I hope it'll help someone else sometime too, this is it all about here after all ^^

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> *"Is it `private` / `public` / something else?"*

Such is called a *global variable*, and it's publicly visible. Anyone can access it just providing a `extern int var;` statement.

> *"can I create a getter/setter for this variable?"*

Yes, you can do (see later explanations)

> *"I can't even include the main.cpp in another since it would be recursive and I'd have main defined infinite times then ....)"*

Of course you can't do this (besides you never want to include `.cpp` files anywhere).
You need some header to declare this interface as being implemented externally, something like

`VarInterface.hpp`

```
#ifndef VARINTERFACE_HPP
#define VARINTERFACE_HPP

extern int var; // Optional, just encapsulating it with the functions is the
                // better choice
int getVar();
void doVar();

#endif // VARINTERFACE_HPP
```

And include it with your implementation in `MyObject.cpp`.

---

As for your [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28817383/how-to-call-a-method-defined-in-main-cpp-from-another-cpp-source-file/28817470#comment45906704_28817383):

> *"what would it do? I just googled and came up with something similar to `static`, is that right? so what's the difference?"*

There's no `private` or `public` access scope policy for free functions (like with the C `static` keyword).

Any function or global variable declaration like shown in the sample above is actually accessible, unless it's placed in an *unnamed namespace*. The latter really restricts linker access to the translation units they are placed in:

`Another.cpp`

```
namespace {
   // These functions and variables are exclusively accessible within
   // Another.cpp
   int var = 0;
   int getVar();
   void doVar();
}
```

But take the above just as a side note, since you want the opposite, as far I've understood from your question.

---

> *"Can you create 'private' fields in it and somehow access them from another .cpp in this project?"*

If you want to hide the `int var;` declaration/definition from other translation units (recommended), you can still do it like

`VarInterface.hpp`

```
#ifndef VARINTERFACE_HPP
#define VARINTERFACE_HPP

int getVar();
void doVar();

#endif // VARINTERFACE_HPP
```

---

`MyObject.cpp`

```
#include "VarInterface.hpp"

namespace {
   int var = 0;
}

int getVar() {
   return var;
}

void doVar() {
    // sth happens with var
}
```

---

`main.cpp`

```
#include "VarInterface.hpp"

int main() {
    MyObject myObj;

    doVar();
}
```

Comment: okay, but I'd need to define the function and the method in my class, would it be 'usable' from my `int main` too?

Comment: @blueBurningCoder _"would it be 'usable' from my `int main()` too?"_ Of course, just include that header in `main.cpp` and `MyObject.cpp` if you need it to be defined there then.

Comment: I mean - It's just the header, not the definition, so it'd be defined everywhere included too? That's the point I'm missing

Comment: @blueBurningCoder I tried to give some more in depth explanation.

Answer (score 0):

Declare any external variables or functions you need:

```
extern int var;
int getVar();
void doVar();
```

either in the source file that uses them, or a header that can be included by any file that wants to use them.

Comment: I'm not that familiar with the 'external' keyword yet - would you mind explaining what you are trying to achieve with it? I'll google it, maybe I can follow it then too

Comment: Okay, so basically I'd need to define them there too wouldn't I?

Comment: @blueburningcoder no, they're already defined once, and mustn't be defined a second time. You just need a declaration to access them from another file.